# How to Transfer packets from one ethernet card to another

Tags: network, monitoring, ethernet

I have a desktop with two ethernet(etho,eth1) cards and OSSIM installed in it. I have a laptop with webmin installed, where i want to write rules for transferring packets from eth1 to eth0. Both the laptop(10.3.2.25) and desktop(10.3.2.148) are in same network

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the role of the laptop. You can put two network cards onto the same network segment by `bridging` them, or by adding `iptables` rules. Neither of these however involve the laptop...

Comment: i am using webmin in my laptop, and ethernet cards are in desktop. How to add rules to iptables? @lynks

Comment: I would suggest you ask this on http://superuser.com/ I have never heard of webmin or ossim, but this is a pretty simple goal to achieve on the linux machine. Remember to include your linux distro also.

Comment: okay, sure. TQ @lynks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have flushed my iptable and added new rules. OSSIM had its own iptables and i dint use webmin.

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 0/0 -i eth0 -d 192.168.10.1 -p TCP -j ACCEPT 

iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth1 -s 192.168.10.0 -d 0/0 -j MASQUERADE 

iptables -A FORWARD -t filter -o eth1 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 

iptables -A FORWARD -t filter -i eth1 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

And it worked out.